# Fedutil Replacement for .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: .net, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs, federated-identity

We currently run a Dynamics CRM IFD application and a few .Net Application under IIS7.5 on .Net Framework 3.5 with ADFS 2.0. We are in the process of upgrading our Apps to .Net Framework 4.5.x and to ADFS 3.0. We use VS 2013 now. W.R.T ADFS it was an easy deployment and maintenance process for ADFS and Certificate Changes, we have been using FedUtil to manage our certificate changes without much of manual changes to the RP applications. If there is a certificate change, it will be updated at the ADFS endpoint and FedUtil will be run and that utility will Automatically update the RP web.configs with the necessary changes.

With the new Identity Model these were deprecated with framework 4.5, my question is how do we achieve a similar administration like the FEDUTIL with the  new model on Framework 4.5. I have read multiple documents on MSDN and there seem to be no direct way to handle the issue explained above. Any insight or recommendation is highly welcome.

Thanks.